# How to run copy command in hidden mode through console?

Tags: c#, .net, console, compiler-errors

i want to copy a file from other drive to c:\windows,i have used this

```
string strCmdLine = " /c xcopy D:\image1.jpg C:\windows";
Process.Start("CMD.exe", strCmdLine);
```

but gives error of

> Unrecognized escape sequence

Comment: This is because `\i` and `\w` escape sequence is not recognized!

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the special `\` character:

```
strCmdLine = " /c xcopy D:\\image1.jpg C:\\windows";
```

or simply:

```
strCmdLine = @" /c xcopy D:\image1.jpg C:\windows";
```

Comment: thnks alot bt i wanna ask for adding @ ?

Comment: @Jason Stathom: Strings beginning with @ are called verbatim strings. They are interpreted as-is, without worrying about special characters, like `\\`. Read some more here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx